# Android fragment and null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to get my fragment working and I cant get it done whatever I am trying to do.

The error I am getting is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Here is the code:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    private TextView one;

    public FragmentOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        one = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.one);

        // Displaying the user details on the screen
        one.setText("kjhbguhjg");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

    }
}
```

Have no idea why it doesn't work. I am testing this class just to see if the text will be changed on the textview. I am using the right id because I checked that like 10 times, yet I think the problem is because textview one is a null object. But why it doesn't find the id?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`onCreate()` is called before `onCreateView()` and therefore you will not be able to access it in `onCreate()`.

**Solution:**
Move

```
one = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.one);
```

to `onViewCreated()` instead.

See picture below for an overview of the [fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

The new snippet looks like this:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {


    private TextView one;

    public FragmentOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        one = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.one);
        // Displaying the user details on the screen
        one.setText("kjhbguhjg");
    }
}
```

[image: Fragment lifecycle]

Comment: You get unreachable errors from your **compiler**. Please double check for syntax errors. Post your full code.

Comment: All my code is in the question, I did as you suggested. I moved  `one = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.one);` to onCreateView just below the  `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);`

Comment: Please reread the answer. Move the statement to **onViewCreated()** and not **onCreateView()**. I edited my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: *sigh... Sorry, I have been trying to get it working way too long and my eyes are already popping out.. **Yes, you are right, works fine now!**

Answer (score 2):

Or. instead of rewriting

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

you can slightly change your onCreateView so it looks like

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false)
one = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.one)
return rootView;
}
```

Comment: you got  unreachable statement error cause you put                                    one = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.one) after return statement, which is final statement for the method.